# Xcode and deprecated warnings not always working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a strange behavior with Xcode (4.3.2) and deprecated warnings, I would like to understand why.
It seems that the deprecated warnings are triggered only on certain methods.
For example (both methods are deprecated):

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

The compiler warn (Correctly) that the method is deprecated.
But:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

doesn't trigger the warning. Why? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the developer docs, you will get like -

1- It is deprecated currently-

`// Frame is ignored.  The size will be specified by the table view width and row height.`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_NA,__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_2_0,__IPHONE_3_0);
```

2- It will be deprecated soon.

`// Display another view controller as a modal child. Uses a vertical sheet transition if animated.This method has been replaced by presentViewController:animated:completion:
// It will be DEPRECATED, plan accordingly.`

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Hope it clears why you are getting warning in first, not in second.

Comment: ok, thanks, I was checking only in the online docs (which only tells "deprecated"), but not in the .h :-)